# Print Google Slide using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, printing

I have written a Google Apps Script (GAS) function to update data in various text boxes in a Google Slide when a button is pressed in a Google Sheet, which works well. Once the function has updated the data in the Slide from the Sheet I have to navigate to the Google Slide, select the File menu and then Print. I would like to automate the manual printing in the GAS function but I haven't been able to find out how to do this.

Unable to find a solution currently, so any input much appreciated.

Comment: This functionality isn't available any more. Check [Migrate from Cloud Print](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9633006#zippy=%2Cprinting-partners) or look for a solution to print to pdf.